# Restlet: Why does chaining ClientResource.getChild() yield siblings rather than nested resources?

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

The following sample attempts to use two different methods to perform path composition for nested resources.  The first uses `ClientResource.getChild()`, while the second creates a new `Reference` from the original ClientResource's reference, and then adds two segments before constructing a new ClientResource for that path.

```
public static void main( String [] args ) {
    // I would expect that this:
    ClientResource res1 = new ClientResource( "http://localhost" );
    ClientResource res2 = res1.getChild( "foo" );
    ClientResource res3 = res2.getChild( "bar" );

    System.out.printf( "res3 points to %s\n", res3.getReference().getTargetRef().toString() );

    // Would be the same as this:
    Reference ref = new Reference( res1.getReference() );
    ref.addSegment( "foo" ).addSegment( "bar" );

    ClientResource res4 = new ClientResource( ref );

    System.out.printf( "res4 points to %s\n", res4.getReference().getTargetRef().toString() );
}
```

Here is the output:

```
res3 points to http://localhost/bar
res4 points to http://localhost/foo/bar
```

Interestingly, if I include a / when creating res2 (`res1.getChild( "foo/" );`), I get the result I was expecting.  However, that doesn't help me if I'm first deriving resource foo, and later want to derive its child resource bar.

So is this a bug, or is there a purpose to this behavior?

Note: I'm using Restlet 2.3.0

**Edit:** This has proven very distressing to me, because the presence of `getChild` was one of the reasons I selected Restlet over Jersey.  Between this apparent bug and the resource path conventions implied by Restlet, I believe I will be using Jersey for future projects.

Comment: Running in same problem. Does anyone know an answer to this question?